# Force throw an exception if affected rowcount is zero

Tags: java, sql, spring

Is there are special method of Spring Framework to throw an exception in case affected rowcount is zero while `UPDATE` operation is performed?

I know the following methods:

`org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException` is used at SELECT operation.

```
int rowCount = this.getJdbcTemplate().update("update");
if (rowCount == 0) {
  throw new Exception(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someday I was looking similar something, I found this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/JdbcUpdateAffectedIncorrectNumberOfRowsException.html

You can define a given number of rows to update, if your SQL update overcome this number, a exception is thrown. I think you can define zero as incorrect number.

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: Actually I want only one row has to be affected, otherwise exceptions is thrown.

Comment: Then you can define one as correct number, if your SQL update overcome this number, a exception is thrown.

Comment: how about when it returns zero??

Comment: this is the constrcutor `JdbcUpdateAffectedIncorrectNumberOfRowsException(String sql,
                                                        int expected,
                                                        int actual)`
you can see the second parameter is about the expected number of rows affected, then any number other than the one defined in the constrcutor is incorrect.